# Unable to set previous value of dropdown from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have multiple dropdown boxes on the page on which I want to restrict users from changing dropdown value, if I have unsaved data on the page.

I know there is an unsaved data on page when `hfSaveFlaghfSaveFlag` value is `true`.

My dropdown lists:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRFP" Width="250" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRFP_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSession" Width="250" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSession_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSessionType" Width="250" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSessionType_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" Width="250" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

My hidden elements:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfPrevValue" runat="server" Value="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSaveFlag" runat="server" Value="false" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

I have set `onchange` and `onfocus` events using code behind

```
ddlRFP.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if(!verifyPendingSave(this)) return false;");
ddlSession.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if(!verifyPendingSave(this)) return false;");
ddlSessionType.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if(!verifyPendingSave(this)) return false;");
ddlCategory.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if(!verifyPendingSave(this)) return false;");

ddlRFP.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "setPreviousValue(this);");
ddlSession.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "setPreviousValue(this);");
ddlSessionType.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "setPreviousValue(this);");
ddlCategory.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "setPreviousValue(this);");
```

Javascript functions

```
function verifyPendingSave(ctrl) {
    if ($("#hfSaveFlag").val() == 'true') {
        alert('You have pending changes on the page.');
        //var control = document.getElementById(ctrl);
        alert($("#hfPrevValue").val());
        alert(ctrl.value);
        ctrl.value = $("#hfPrevValue").val();
        return false;
}
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function setPreviousValue(ctrl) {
    $("#hfPrevValue").val(ctrl.value);
}
```

I tried to capture previous selection using `onfocus` and use it to re-assign when a `change` event fires and there is unsaved data on the page.

When I click on a dropdown, it is executing `setPreviousValue` and storing the correct selected value in `hfPrevValue`.

Now, when I choose a different item from the dropdown, it seems to be executing `onfocus` again before change event resulting in loss of stored previous value.  I am not able to reset the value selected prior to the current selection.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Could you provide more details. I am not seeing any event handler defined. U can try jsfiddle.net

Comment: @gaurav - added code

Comment: Create a [mcve] that reproduces problem. Description is hard to follow

Comment: @charlietfl - added more explanation and rephrased question